# How to upload laravel project to github without allowing git to modify the project itself

Tags: git, bash, laravel, github

I'm new to github and right now, I'm trying to my upload my laravel project to github.

I've successfully upload the github project, however whenever i add my folder throught git bash, it always show warning that some file inside the laravel project will be replaced with CRLF, and I guess this is one of the reason why I cant run my laravel project after I clone it/download it from my github repository.

I've been trying to update my composer with composer update, but when i go to public folder of laravel, it show Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.(2 times)

The error showed on console is Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Note: Original project is fine, the downloaded one doesn't work

how to fix this?

Comment: "I guess this is one of the reason why I cant run my laravel project" <-- that's probably a wrong assumption.

Comment: @jszobody hmmmm.....how to solve this?

Comment: Solve _what_ exactly? You haven't provided details of any specific issue. If you're getting an error message trying to run Laravel, you need to post a question with those details, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: @jszobody updated :D

Comment: A 500 error means _look at your error logs_. Find the specific error details, otherwise all we can do is shoot in the dark. This likely has nothing to do with git at all.

Comment: @jszobody ok solved! just need to run composer install + add  .env to downloaded project :D

Comment: Excellent! Amazing how easy it become once you're looking at actual error messages. =)

Comment: @jszobody I learn new things today! ty :D

Answer (score 1):

Based on my case, If you want to run laravel project that you downloaded from github:

1. Run composer install on command prompt above your downloaded folder
2. add .env file to laravel project
3. Ready to go and enjoy!